# how to use tqdm progress bar in dask_cudf and cudf

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tqdm, cudf

I can use `tqdm` progress bar in pandas for example:

```
tqdm.pandas()
df = df['var'].progress_apply(lambda x: something(x))
```

can i do same in thing `cudf` or `dask_cudf` if not then how can i use tqdm progress bar in it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until `progress_apply` is available, you would have to implement an equivalent yourself (e.g. using [`apply_chunks`](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/api.html?highlight=apply#cudf.core.dataframe.DataFrame.apply_chunks)). Just a sketch of the code:

```
full_size = 100
t = tqdm(total=full_size)
def chunks_generator():
    chunk_size = 5
    for s in range(0,full_size,chunk_size):
        yield s
        t.update(s)

df.apply_chunks(..., chunks=chunks_generator())
```